# Array data type, split string,

Tags: mysql

I'm currently working on a function in MYSQL, I have a comma delimited string (1,22,344,55) from another table, How can I split this in MYSQL to an array (NOT temp_table). Also, is there a similar function in MYSQL where I can do foreach()?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

MySQL does not include a function to split a delimited string. However, it’s very easy to create your own function.

```
CREATE FUNCTION SPLIT_STR(
  x VARCHAR(255),
  delim VARCHAR(12),
  pos INT
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
RETURN REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos),
       LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos -1)) + 1),
       delim, '');
```

Usage

```
SELECT SPLIT_STR(string, delimiter, position)
```

From here: 
http://blog.fedecarg.com/2009/02/22/mysql-split-string-function/

Answer (score 7):

The correct usage in MySQL is:

```
SELECT FIND_IN_SET('b','a,b,c,d');
```

Gives as result: 2

Comment: this is the best and quickest solution also for mariaDB.

Answer (score 1):

SQL's version of foreach is called a [cursor](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cursors.html)