# Related Products SQL Query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, sql-like

I am trying to show something similar to related products on on my website. I have tested the following query, and I get no errors; but I get no results either.

```
<?php 
    $relatedStmt = $db->query("SELECT * FROM items WHERE tag LIKE id = 1 LIMIT 3");
?>
```

I also tried `%1%` and it displayed ALL the results, I assumed the code was thinking the query was just `SELECT * FROM items`.

The tags in the column are displayed in the following format: `tagone two three four`, so I am trying to display the products that have similar tags, hence why I used the `LIKE` clause.

[Table screenshot](http://gyazo.com/db7d851f485cd8bff96a8a2680a4ba03)

The current query is to relate with this query: `SELECT * FROM items WHERE id = 1`. So `LIKE id = 1` is to find the tags that match this query to show the related products.

Comment: Can you show us a sample of the table?

Comment: Think of `LIKE` as `CONTAINS` - `WHERE tag LIKE "%red%" will find all rows where the tag *contains* the string `red`

Comment: @ncdreamy I have updated the question with a table screenshot.

Comment: Ok, so what are you trying to extract from that table? You query makes no sense when looking at the table.

Comment: @ncdreamy I am trying to check the `tag` column. So if it matches with the current sql query on the page, then show the similar products. The current SQL query is `SELECT * FROM items WHERE id = 1`.

Comment: @cale_b So it cannot be a full column? Only a string?

Comment: per screen print your tag column hold different kind of value. not sure what this is `WHERE tag LIKE id = 1`? what's the desired result?

Comment: @Rahul Im wanting to display the products that have the same tag(s) as  the id=1 product.

Comment: in that case you can simply do `SELECT * FROM items WHERE tag = (select tag from items where id = 1)` but that same as saying `SELECT * FROM items WHERE id = 1`. I am really confused with your question.

Comment: @Rahul, that query gave a result but it doesn't explode the tags (as the LIKE clause emulated). So the tag column has to be the exact match, there not separated by " "'s.

Comment: @Rahul Also just tried `where id like 1`, it gave the same result.

Comment: The way you are trying is totally wrong. `WHERE tag LIKE id = 1` makes no sense at all and completely a wrong construct. You should simply do `where id =1`. If there is specific result needed then edit your post and clarify the same. I think you are totally confused.

Comment: @Rahul the LIKE clause, gathers something LIKE something, as = gathers something EXACTLY as something. Example; john walked down the road. = john walked down the road. | john walked down the road LIKE john.

Comment: Given your table screenshot, am I correct that what you expect from your related entries query is item id 5?

Comment: @ob1quixote Correct, as it uses `buttons` `vector` `psd`.

Answer (score 1):

[`LIKE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like) doesn't work the way you seem to expect. It's a character for character comparison, with wildcards, between the operands.

Of the mysql functions, closest to what you want is probably [`LOCATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_locate) or [`FIND_IN_SET`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set). There are split solutions in other questions, *e.g.* ["Can Mysql Split a column?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1096679/3484133) and ["Split a MYSQL string from GROUP_CONCAT into an ( array, like, expression, list) that IN () can understand"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4650238/3484133). However, even so there is no good way to compare the individual tags in your concatenated `tag` column with the individual tags of the other rows in your table.

Therefore, I think you'd be better off moving the tags into their own table with `item_id` as a foreign key. Then the solution is [trivial (SQLFiddle)](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/10ef0f/3):

```
-- Related Items
SELECT *
  FROM items
 WHERE id in (SELECT DISTINCT item_id
                FROM tags t
                JOIN (SELECT tag
                        FROM tags
                       WHERE item_id = 1
                      ) t1 ON t1.tag = t.tag
               WHERE item_id != 1
              )
;
```

Answer (score 0):

i am unsure about that `id = 1` thing in your query but anyway you could try this: `SELECT * FROM items WHERE tag LIKE '%search_this_tag%' LIMIT 3`

Comment: Note that without ORDER BY, LIMIT is pretty much meaningless

Comment: I'm not trying to search an exact tag. Im wanting to match the tags with the id=1 row.

Comment: @Strawberry Thanks, i'll get that changed on my side.