# mysql search for multiple substring in single column

Tags: mysql, where-clause

I need an efficient way to search multiple sub string in same column of a table. Following is the sample table and inefficient query I create. Can any one help me to make it more dynamic.

```
id | column_2 | column_2
1  | 65,35    | 14,13,20
2  | 41,15,16 | 10,21,23
3  | 12,14,15 | 10,12,20

SELECT * FROM `table1` WHERE `column_2` LIKE '%10%' AND `column_2` LIKE '%23%';
```

These values will be lengthy and the and condition also will be dynamic in amount. So is there any efficient way to create query for remove and condition (having).

Comment: You have two column_2's. Should that actually be column_2 and column_3? Also, could you explain a bit about the problem? This table is begging to be split up into two or three tables. That would significant improve the speed of your queries. Do you have control over the database design?

Comment: Don't store comma separated values in a single column. The problem you have with the query stems directly from that bad design choice.

Comment: search projected to column 2 only. And searching for occurrence of 10 and 23. this is scalable and also values won't be next each other.

Comment: Instead of posting an answer i consider to upvote the comment by *a_horse_with_no_name*

Comment: Is there a tutorial that people follow which makes them store comma-separated values in columns? This is appearing day after day, and the solution is what @a_horse_with_no_name said. Just don't do it. Use tables to store **relations**. It is called **relational** database for a reason. What you did here is made it into a glorified text file.

Comment: @N.B.: what confuses me even more is that **every** time this comes up the answer is "I didn't design it this way, and I can't change it". I wonder why there are so many databases where this is done if nobody did it...

Comment: Also note that LIKE '%23%' would match ...,235,... too, which is probably not what you want

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: I appreciate your suggestion. But the this piece I create for example. My real application need unavoidable complex logic with some Hindus astrology calculations. And particular function won't be used heavily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I took the function `SPLIT_STR` from here: [MYSQL - Array data type, split string,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4078838/mysql-array-data-type-split-string)

#### Our data-set

Assume we have the following data set;

```
select * from a_table;
+----+-------------+
| id | column2     |
+----+-------------+
|  1 | 10,11,23    |
|  2 | 5,14,23     |
|  3 | 2,18        |
|  4 | 23,10,11    |
|  5 | 230,100,110 |
|  6 | 11,100      |
+----+-------------+
6 rows in set
```

#### The function

We then create the function (referenced above);

```
CREATE FUNCTION SPLIT_STR(
  x VARCHAR(255),
  delim VARCHAR(12),
  pos INT
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
RETURN REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos),
       LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos -1)) + 1),
       delim, '');
```

#### The final query

From there, we can do a simple query;

```
SELECT id from a_table WHERE SPLIT_STR(column2, ",", 1) IN (10,23)
```

This will give the following result set;

```
SELECT id from a_table WHERE SPLIT_STR(column2, ",", 1) IN(10,23);
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  1 |
|  4 |
+----+
2 rows in set
```

#### To add more numbers

To add more numbers, simply add to the `IN()` function - comma separated values.

#### A note

Deeply consider [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26196359/mysql-search-for-multiple-substring-in-single-column/26237490#comment41077857_26196359)

> Don't store comma separated values in a single column. The problem you have with the query stems directly from that bad design choice. –  *a_horse_with_no_name*

Comment: @hd: is it a problem of using ","? can i use another character to separate those values? Or are you recommending to avoid multi values from the column? because i'm ok to replace "," with another character. But avoid multi value on the column will make a major design change on my program.

Comment: And seems this query apply "OR" condition. is it possible to apply AND for this "REGEXP". Only if the column have 10 and 23 return the column. Currently either 10 or 23 is returning the column.

Comment: This regexp matches (e.g) "910". `(,|^)x(,|$)` seems to address this case.

Comment: @RandomSeed I'm not following, sorry! Sugunan the comma (",") is actually what's holding you back, it's bad design - look into normalisation. I'm looking into using an AND condition now.

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ `SELECT "910" REGEXP "10(,|$)";` wrongly returns `TRUE`, whereas `SELECT "910" REGEXP "(,|^)10(,|$)";` returns `FALSE` as expected. Therefore the pattern to use is `(,|^)x(,|$)`.

Comment: @sugunan I've updated my answer. Moved away from using a regular expression. Check it out :)

Comment: @hd: This is perfectly fit into my requirement. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

To search In a mysql tables structure you can use either a way

1. To search with *like operator using %search string%*
2. You can use mysql built in function `FIND_IN_SET()`

```
 SELECT  *
 FROM    tableName
 WHERE   FIND_IN_SET('10', column name)  AND
 FIND_IN_SET('23', column name)
```

3. Third way you can use is to create a string from your programming code by appending search keywords, to search for that corresponding sequence in the table.

Comment: using multiple "and" is the one I wanted to avoid. Here same applies again.

Comment: Did you try using 3rd way

Comment: Do u hv to do it client side or server side?

Comment: These values will come from html multiselect box as array. And php will compile the query string. But I feel better to avoid the dynamic number of and condition. Because it is going to have 12 multi select box with 9 values per each. So total possible and will be 12x9

Comment: Yeah i got ur point so its better you use last option,make a string by appending the vales and then srarch for its occurance it will not only redure your query time but also search efficiently,you can seach that appened string in Find-in-set it will be perfect.