# How to split up a comma separated table into multiple rows using MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to implement splitting of a column into rows based upon a delimiter and I came across this.

[Turning a Comma Separated string into individual rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493510/turning-a-comma-separated-string-into-individual-rows)

It describes a solution using SQL. Can anyone suggest a MySQL equivalent of this solution?

Comment: Either a) describe what the `STUFF` function actually does or b) ask the actual question for the problem you have (which appears to be splitting CSV data into separate rows) - who cares *what* function is used to solve it?

Comment: You don't need the stuff function or a mysql equivalent (it doesn't do what you need). You can use the function from [MYSQL - Array data type, split string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4078838/mysql-array-data-type-split-string) to split up your array for the solution of your link.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL split values to multiple rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17942508/sql-split-values-to-multiple-rows)