# Get difference between two comma separated values in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Need to get the difference between two commas separated strings, See the below example for better understanding.

```
String 1: 1,2,3,4
String 2: 1,4 or 
String 2: 2,3 or 
String 2: 3,1 etc..
```

Now I need to get a result as the difference between two string like

```
Example 1:

    String 1: 1,2,3,4
    String 2: 1,4

Required Output: 2,3

Example 2:

   String 1: 1,2,3,4
   String 2: 2,3

Required Output: 1,4
```

Would you please help me how can I do it in `MySQL` query or procedure or function?

Comment: I think use `procedure` with temp table can solve it more easy

Comment: This might serve as a start :https://stackoverflow.com/a/38873032/4180382

Comment: You could save yourself a world of pain by normalising your schema

Comment: @Strawberry Did you mean that there is no solution for that?

Comment: No, but look how convoluted the suggested solution is.

Comment: Yes, but I waiting until getting the perfect one.

Comment: @Kamlesh . . . The "perfect" suggestion is to fix your data structure.  You should not be storing numbers as strings.  Nor should you be storing lists in a single string column.  That is the right answer.  Strawberry is correct.

Comment: @GordonLinoff You are correct but if I will get solution anyhow for the above scenario then it would really helpful for other methodologies as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you always use two specified string only then try this

```
Select group_concat(x.c)
From 
(
  Select substring('1,2,3,4', (r * 2) -1 , 1) as c
  From (
  Select  @curRow := @curRow + 1 as r
  from sometable JOIN    (SELECT @curRow := 0) r
  WHERE   @curRow< (length('1,2,3,4') - length(replace('1,2,3,4', ',', '')))+1
  ) a
) x  
Where x.c not in (Select substring('1,4', (r * 2) -1 , 1) as c
                  From (
                          Select  @curRow := @curRow + 1 as r
                          from sometable
                                  JOIN (SELECT @curRow := 0) r
                          WHERE @curRow< (length('1,4') - length(replace('1,4', ',', '')))+1
                  ) a)
```

Note: If you want to compare more than two string then put this query into the function and pass the two string parameter and apply those parameter to this query

Comment: Can I know why the files_status_log table is required here?

Comment: no you add some table which have n rows. I have corrected the query

Comment: Must the table be required?

Comment: it will be easy choice

Comment: Ok, I will try it once and update you soon, It is fine for me or not.

Answer (score 0):

It would be good if you create a function that get two string as input and return string.

Comment: Ok, Would you please suggest which type of function should I need to implement here?