# How to match comma separated string against comma separated MySQL field

Tags: mysql

I’m trying to match comma separated string against comma separated MySQL field. This should match one more comma separated text.

Example

String = `apple, pineapple, grapes`

MySQL field = `mango, oranges, apple`

I tried `MySQL IN` but it only works if string exactly match the MySQL filed or if there is only one item in the string

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE field_1 IN (‘string’)
```

Also tried `FIND_IN_SET` without any luck. Can anyone tell me how to achieve this? Appreciate your help.

Comment: You have a comma-separated string in your table? Then you should not be interested in its separate values at all. If you *are* interested in separate values, then change your data model and store the values separately.

Comment: I think the options are straightforward; either normalise your schema, or don't bother with an RDBMS

Comment: @Strawberry i think i will go with normalizing the schema. Thank you.

Comment: @max You should have to make this table to more normal form, or else declare that field as json field and store josn. Mysql have powerful function to play with json fields

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to achieve above result to match records, execute following script

> Create temporary table with input string as rows by , separated

```
drop temporary table if exists temp;
create temporary table temp( val varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci )
DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
set @sql = concat("insert into temp (val) values ('", replace(( select 
group_concat(distinct ('mango,oranges,apple')) as data ), ",", "'),('"),"');");
prepare stmt1 from @sql;
execute stmt1;
```

> Join temp table with main table

```
select *
from
(
     select distinct(val) as a from temp
)as splited
inner join 
(
    select 'apple, pineapple, grapes' as field
 )as table1
 where table1.field like concat('%',splited.a,'%');
```

Comment: Just run this queries, you well get idea about to fit in your requirements. @max

Comment: @max If you found this answer is helpful then please make it accept. Thanks

Comment: Just did. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4078881/3037607) might help you out. Just convert the cell value and the query value to an array, and then check if they have a matching value.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like your question is wrong. 
you have mentioned as

```
MySQL field = mango, oranges, apple
```

and your query is

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE field_1 IN (‘string’)
```

Make sure whether it is field name or field values

Comment: They are correct. this is just a example of the query i tried.